# Red Gate MySQL Compare showing similar objects shown in the differences group

Tags: mysql, sql, redgate, schema-compare

I am doing a MySQL Red Gate schema compare and there are objects being shown in the differences group, but the compare view shows no differences. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you choose all columns in when comparing them?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
    phone, 
    COUNT(phone) AS NumOccurrences
FROM 
    *MyTable*
GROUP BY 
    phone
HAVING ( 
    COUNT(phone) > 1 
)
```